# How to properly override variables of an Angular Library

Tags: css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, sass

I am basically making a small design library using bootstrap 5 and Angular.
I am using boostrap core, add some extension or custom style to it (to fit my design).

Basically, I use bootstrap as follow :

**LIBRARY :**

I have 2 scss in my library :

design-library.core.scss

```
// Required to be imported for bootstrap
@import '~bootstrap/scss/functions';

// Library default variable that override bootstraps one
@import './variables';
```

design-library.extension.scss

```
// I need to import the variables or they are undefined 

@import './variables'
// some override of bootstrap style like 
.alert {
  background: $white;
}
```

**PROJECT :**

Now, In my project, I use the design-library as follow :

project.scss

```
// Import the default variable of the libraryu
@import '~/design-library.core';

// override the default with additional variables
@import './project-variables'

// import bootstrap
@import '~bootstrap';

// import the extension of bootstrap from the library
@import '~/design-library.extension'
```

This works great, the problem I have tho, is with variables overrides.

Let's say I put `$red: #f00` as default in the library.

Then, In the project variables I set `$red: #e30000`

In my library extension when import `variables`, I import the one of the library (since I can't import the one of the project of course...). But since I import the one from the Library (and not the override one), all my CSS will be generated with `$red: #f00`. I want instead all my extension css to use overridden variable so it should be `$red: #e30000`

How can I import variable after they have been overridden by the project that implements them ?

EDIT : Is this clear enough ? :x

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to override some variables within `design-library.extension.scss`. The only way to do that is by importing another file.

```
@import './variables'
@import './overrides'
// some override of bootstrap style like 
.alert {
  background: $white;
}
```

However, it sounds like you want this file to somehow know that you've overridden these variables in the `project.scss` file. Sorry, but that just doesn't make sense.

When you override the variables in `project.scss` they have not been "overridden by the project", they've only been overridden in that one single file. For your extension to know of these overrides, it would need to import `project.scss`.

That being said, I do not recommend trying to import external files if you plan on releasing this library as a package, that would make it extremely fragile.

If this is just for personal use, you can import your `project-variables` file after `./variables` in `design-library.extension.scss`.

I hope that clarifies things for you.